# Identity Server V3

Tags: identityserver3

I have an identity server implementation set up with our website and users can log in locally or with external providers and everything is working fine.

We now have a requirement where a customer wants to log onto their local system and have a link from their system to ours, effectively they wont have to log into our system again so they would send us a token that we would verify.

Has anyone any experience with this kind of set up and could give me any pointers on how they have done it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you configure the customer as just another OpenID relying party.

If you *must* log in from the customer's system, look into [Resource Owner Flow](http://oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2/grants/password.html). There is an IdentityServer3 [sample console application](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/ConsoleResourceOwnerClient). Here is my walk-through for creating an [MVC application](http://web.workstate.com/blog/workstate-codes-oauth2-resource-owner-flow-with-identityserver3).

Resource owner flow is less than ideal; you must completely trust the customer's local system with user credentials.

Comment: Thanks.  I will have a look at using a Resource Owner flow and see how I get on.